Multiple requests in Python with `asyncio`
I'm trying to make a number of requests at the same time.
I'm new to async and await in Python (I've used it in Js).
I found an example and used this:
import asyncio
import aiohttp

async def get_item( session: aiohttp.ClientSession, path: str ):
    # fetch data
    url = f'my/path/here{path}'
    resp = await session.request('GET', url=url)
    data = await resp.json()
    # at this point I do stuff to the data and save as csv
    return await data


async def get_all():
    tasks = []
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks.append(get_item(session=session, path='1'))
        tasks.append(get_item(session=session, path='2'))

    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
    
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(get_all())


but I get the following error:
RuntimeError: This event loop is already running
Obviously there is an issue, please can someone explain what the issue is and how I can fix this?

did you run this as a python script or in a jupyter notebook ?

I used this in jupyter notebook. Is this the issue? I tried your solution and get an error.

You'll need a top-level runner like asyncio.run, this behavior of get_event_loop implicitly creating an event loop is deprecated since Python 3.10.
import asyncio
import aiohttp


async def get_item(session: aiohttp.ClientSession, path: str):
    url = f"https://httpbin.org/{path}"
    async with session.get(url) as resp:
        return await resp.json()

async def get_all():
    tasks = []
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(get_item(session=session, path="json")))
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(get_item(session=session, path="json")))
        responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)

    for i, json in enumerate(responses):
        print(i, json["slideshow"]["author"])


asyncio.run(get_all())

I've also fixed up some other stylistic things and used an example URL which returns json, for demonstration purposes.

Within a Jupyter notebook, there will already be an event loop running. A top-level runner may not be used, and you will see this error:
RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop

In this case, you can just use async/await at the top level, i.e. replace:
asyncio.run(get_all())

with:
await get_all()


nice clean answer, well done.  my answer was more generic...

@D.L Thanks, yours works too but it's not using aiohttp library at all ..

It looks like the code is gatering tasks. If this is the case i would use a recipie like this:

Replace the get_all() with a main() which is the conventional entry point.
in the main function, remove the return await. it is not needed.
I just simulate a task in get_item, but you can make an HTTP (or other) request if you wish to.

so the sample code will look like this:

import asyncio

# Define an asynchronous function
async def get_item(task_number):
    print(f"Task {task_number}: Start fetching")
    await asyncio.sleep(2)  # Simulate a network operation
    print(f"Task {task_number}: Done fetching")
    return {f'data_{task_number}': 123}

# Define the main entry point of the program
async def main():
    # Create a list of tasks to be run concurrently
    tasks = [get_item(i) for i in range(1, 4)]
    results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    for result in results:
        print("Result:", result)

# Run the 'main' function
asyncio.run(main())


the result will look like this:
Task 1: Start fetching
Task 2: Start fetching
Task 3: Start fetching
Task 1: Done fetching
Task 2: Done fetching
Task 3: Done fetching
Result: {'data_1': 123}
Result: {'data_2': 123}
Result: {'data_3': 123}


I copied and pasted this code into a new file and I get the following error asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop

I think it's something to do with jupyter notebook

yes,  it is.  the event loop cannot run in a notebook or in an interactive session. it runs from a normal python file...
